# Android crashes reported in DigitsActivity, DigitsActionBarActivity, FailureActivityDelegateImpl

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Crashlytics is reporting crashes that happen in `DigitsActivity`, `DigitsActionBarActivity`, `FailureActivityDelegateImpl`.

Crash is: Fatal Exception: `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: This activity can only be started from Digits`

I get this crash reported a few times for each on **every** build we release.

These activities are apparently a part of the Fabric/Twitter SDK to sign in with a phone number. However, I am not using them at all! Anyone have an explanation for what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Digit's, you could try to only include the [Twitter-Core](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/twitter-core.html):

Upgrade your gradle to:

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And your application's onCreate to:

```
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig));
```